# OpenGL. Ball to ball collision

Tags: collision-detection

Making a probability machine in OpenGL.

```
Ball ballArray[5];

while(elapsed > 0)
{
     timeStep = m_Timer.getSeconds();
     for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BALLS; ++i)
     {
        ballArray[i].updateBall(timeStep); // where collision with pegs dealt 
        //ballArray[0].ballBallCollision(timeStep,ballArray[0],ballArray[1]);
      }
      Redraw();
}
```

I can't get the commented line working :(
How do I pass 2 instances of ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ballBallCollision()` works, you probably want to collide each ball with every other ball, i.e. 0 with 1, 0 with 2, 1 with 2 etc. You will need a second loop for this.

My preferred solution is to create a loop that runs over all the remaining balls like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BALLS; ++i)
{
   ballArray[i].updateBall(timeStep); // where collision with pegs dealt 
   for(int j = i + 1; i < NUMBER_OF_BALLS; ++j)
   {
      ballArray[i].ballBallCollision(timeStep,ballArray[i],ballArray[j]);
   }
}
```

Note that, since we start at `i + 1`, we never get a ball to collide with each other (0 with 0), and we don't check each pair twice (we check 0 against 1, but not 1 against 0 again).

Comment: When I do that, all of my balls freeze at the top :(

Comment: @RashedHassan: it would appear your `ballBallCollision` code does not work as assumed, then. I'd recommend getting it to work on two single Balls, not in an array, without for loops. Then you can generalize to `NUMBER_OF_BALLS` balls.

Comment: Thanks man. Your algorithm worked fine. I re-wrote my ball-ball collision stuffs. Now it works fine.
Was looking up online about round-robin league stuffs, but that for loop works peach! cheers xD